# If $f>0$, calculate $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n \log\left(1+\left(\frac{f}{n} \right)^{\alpha} \right)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

If $f>0$, calculate $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n \log\left(1+\left(\frac{f}{n} \right)^{\alpha} \right)$.﻿

Comment: 1. You get different results depending on the value of $\alpha$ 2. Don't put the question in both the title and body of your post 3. What have you tried?

Comment: I have made the changes in the answer

Comment: What attempts have you made, so other users know your skill level? I do not know what your post means and have never seen any maths like that until now, but I clicked on because you had $-2$ votes. I think this could be why...

Comment: Are you taking to me?

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n \log\left(1+\left(\frac{f}{n} \right)^{\alpha} \right)=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\log\left(1+\left(\frac{f}{n} \right)^{\alpha} \right)^n$$
$$\implies$$
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n \log\left(1+\left(\frac{f}{n} \right)^{\alpha} \right)=f\iff \alpha=1$$
$$\land$$
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n \log\left(1+\left(\frac{f}{n} \right)^{\alpha} \right)=0\iff \alpha>1$$
$$\land$$
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}n \log\left(1+\left(\frac{f}{n} \right)^{\alpha} \right)=\infty\iff \alpha<1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \ln \Big(\Big(1+\Big(\frac{f}{n}\Big)^{\alpha}\Big)^n\Big)$$

> So we know
>   $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \big(1+f(x)\big)^{g(x)}$$
>   Such  that 
>   $$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0$$
>   &
>   $$\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)=\infty$$
>   We can write,
>   $$\lim_{x\to \infty} (1+f(x))^{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to \infty} e^{f(x) g(x)}$$

As $n\to \infty$
$$\bigg(\frac{f}{n}\bigg)^{\alpha} \to 0 \iff \alpha \gt 0$$
Assuming $\alpha\gt 0$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \ln \Biggr( \biggr(1+\bigg(\frac{f}{n}\bigg)^{\alpha}\biggr)^n\Biggr)$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \ln \big( e^{\frac{f^{\alpha}}{n^{\alpha-1}}}\big)$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f^{\alpha}}{n^{\alpha-1}}$$
For full answer

> If $\alpha \gt 1$$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f^{\alpha}}{n^{\alpha-1}}=0$$If $\alpha =1$$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f^{\alpha}}{n^{\alpha-1}}=f^{\alpha}$$If$\alpha \lt 1$$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f^{\alpha}}{n^{\alpha-1}}=\infty$$

For proof of identity I used,

> We know$$e=\lim_{x\to \infty} (1+f(x))^{\frac{1}{f(x)}}$$Such that$$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=0$$Now for$$\lim_{x\to \infty} (1+f(x))^{g(x)}$$$$\lim_{x\to \infty} (1+f(x))^{\frac{1}{f(x)}f(x)g(x)}$$$$\lim_{x\to \infty} ((1+f(x))^{\frac{1}{f(x)}})^{f(x)g(x)}$$Now using definition of e$$\lim_{x\to \infty} e^{f(x)g(x)}$$

Comment: RIght here  you are taking g(x)=x, right?  but this doesn't  tends to  0 as x  tends   to  infinity

Comment: Sorry my mistake